# What differences should I expect between Postgres migration scripts for 9.6 vs later versions?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, postgresql-9.6

**Background:**
In one of our projects there is a Jenkins build step which generates a Postgres SQL script based on provided EF Core DbContext. The script generating step looks like

```
dotnet-ef migrations script -c MyDbContext
```

Since there is a requirement to generate a script for different versions of Postgres, the following steps are taken:

1. Postgres version is being set in C# code via `SetPostgresVersion` extension method
2. Version which is being set in step 1 is being passed as Environment variable.

These version-setting steps are working because I've got an error while trying to pass version '12' instead of required '12.0', the scripts are also generated without issues.

**Question:**
I need to come up with the first (lowest) Postgres version for which the generated script will be different from the baseline 9.6.
**I have generated SQL scripts for Postgres 9.6, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 13.1 and they all are identical.
This might be a correct result, but how do I verify it? What differences should I expect between, let's say, 9.6 and higher versions of Postgres (if indeed such differences exist)?**

The actions performed in the migration script are following:

1. If a table does not exist then create it
2. If an index does not exist then create it
3. Insert records into MigrationHistory
4. Alter some tables, drop some columns and indexes, etc.

It is possible that the actions performed by the script are indeed the same for different Postgres versions, but is there any way to verify it?

Comment: I wouldn't think you need to test each _minor_ version. So only one check for 9.6, 10,11,12 and 13 should be enough. Note the version numbering scheme changed with Postgres 10. While 9.5 -> 9.6 was a major version change, after v10 the second digit is the _minor_ release. So the next major upgrade is 10 -> 11.  So it's absolutely no surprise that e.g. 13.0 and 13.1 yielded the same result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your interest in this question. Indeed, I was generating the scripts for major versions assuming that if there were no changes between, lets say, 11.0 and 12.0 then all 11.x versions will also have no changes.

Comment: To see what difference you should expect, you can try adding identity column to your DbContext. According to https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/generated-properties.html#defining-the-default-strategy-for-the-entire-model . Prior to v10 Postgres used serial columns for implementing identity columns. Starting from 10 it got a new IDENTITY feature. So this type of columns should look differently in 9.6 and 10 migrations.